# Is there an upper limit on entropy density?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, perpetual-motion

I would like to sell you a perpetual motion machine that works by making the insides of a box continually more messy. The engine comes packaged with a physicist who will continually discover new thermodynamic degrees of freedom inside the box so that it can be kept running. He has until the gasoline runs out to make his first discovery.

Can a purely thermodynamic argument be mounted against this pitch? If not, is there some good reason to expect that my associate will eventually have to stop discovering new degrees of freedom?

Comment: I didn't understand your sell-pitch really (in my understanding, a higher entropy is really indicative of non-usable energy--which seems to be the opposite of what seem to have in mind but I don't really claim to have understood your pitch.). But, there is indeed some upper limit on entropy that can reside within a certain mass, which is the entropy of a blackhole of that mass. [...]

Comment: If the entropy on the inside of the box can increase without bound, the engine can decrease the entropy on the outside without bound, without violating thermodynamics.

Comment: [...] This doesn't give you an upper limit on the volume-density of entropy per se, but it gives you an upper-limit on the area-density of entropy (this is, in the tree-level calculation. In natural units, this limit is $\frac{1}{4}$. When you include loop corrections, the entropy of a blackhole starts depending on the logarithm of the area in the subleading order--and you clearly don't even have an upper-limit on areal-density of entropy per se.) But, once you specify a volume $V$, there is a maximal entropy which it can withhold--just that this maximal limit is not proportional to $V$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. But no, to summarize, there isn't an upper limit on the density of the entropy but there is an upper limit on the entropy itself that can reside in a given volume. The non-existence of the upper limit on the density means that the upper limit on the entropy (in a given volume) doesn't vary in proportion to the volume itself. So, you cannot pack an indefinite amount of entropy in a given volume. When you start stuffing a volume with entropy, it will eventually become a blackhole and then the blackhole will keep growing in size as you add more entropy to it.

Comment: @DvijMankad "there isn't an upper limit on the density of the entropy but there is an upper limit on the entropy itself that can reside in a given volume", how is this not an oxymoron?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Haha. The entropy of a blackhole $S\sim r^2 $. Thus, since a given volume $V$ determines the radius $r \sim V^{\frac{1}{3}}$, the maximal entropy that can reside in that $V$ is $S_{V}\sim V^{\frac{2}{3}}$. Let's say the proportionality constant is some $k$, then there is an unambiguous upper-limit on entropy in a given volume $V$ given by $S_V=kV^{\frac{2}{3}}$. And thus, the maximum entropy-density for a volume goes as $V^{\frac{-1}{3}}$. Thus, there is no absolute upper limit on density per se. Only a limit on entropy (and density) for a given volume.

Comment: @DvijMankad I did not think of that! +1